# How do I make my bot delete a channel after some time has passed?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm a little bit lost here, how do I make my bot delete a channel after some time has passed? Such as 3 seconds.

Code:

```js
        if((message.author.bot) && (message.channel.name.includes('closed')) && (message.author.id === "id")){
      for (let embed of message.embeds) {
         if(embed.description.includes('custom msg')){   
            setTimeout(function(){ 
              message.channel.delete
            }, 3000); 
          }
        }
      }
```

Have a great rest of your day!

Comment: `message.channel.delete` is actually a method instead of a variable like you have written in your code. Change it to `message.channel.delete()` and you should be good to go!

Comment: Hey @Caladan, I made the change you suggested but my bot still manages to not delete the channel.

Comment: Do you get any error in your console?

Comment: I don't get any errors.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why it is not working for you. When I try out your code, everything works for me. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested this code out and it worked for me, give it a try and see what it does

```js
// just verifying here, please double check the statement below becuase that is what is going to trigger the bot

// if a bot sends a message in a channel whose name includes 'closed' and that bots id is "id" then 
if (message.author.bot && message.channel.name.includes('closed') && message.author.id === "id") {
    message.channel.messages.fetch().then(messages => {
        messages.forEach(message => {
            const embed = message.embed[0]
            if (embed) {
                if (embed.description.includes('custom msg')) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        message.channel.delete()
                    }, 3000)
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

If that comment above the if statement is wrong and needs to be adjusted, let me know and we can fix it